# Cypress Testing is Not Working whereas Manual Testing is

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing, manual-testing

I have been using the Cypress testing tool for end to end tests.
However, when it comes to saving and displaying certain data, it'll save when done manually but not when the Cypress bot runs through it. You can even do it manually through the Cypress UI and it'll work, just not when run by the tests.

This Error is coming from Cypress:
`(xhr)POST 500 <current URL here>`

This error is coming up in the console:

> Failed to load the resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

[image: The Error]

Followed by:

> AxiosError
> code: "ERR_BAD_RESPONSE"
> config: {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
> message: "Request failed with status code 500"
> name: "AxiosError"
> request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
> response: {data: {…}, status: 500, statusText: 'Internal Server Error', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}
> stack: "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500\n    at settle (http://localhost:1234/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=4b79c220:1189:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:1234/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=4b79c220:1417:7)"
> [[Prototype]]
> : Error

I am using the Chrome browser, Windows, VSCode as the IDE, and a Bash terminal, if that helps.

I originally thought it was an origin issue, because the data being saved is calculated through Google Maps, but even when the ChromeWebSecurity is false, nothing changes.

I have been opening Cypress with `npx cypress open --config chromeWebSecurity=false`, and `chromeWebSecurity: false` is in the cypress.config.ts file.

I thought maybe it was local storage between tests which wasn't saving, although it made little to no sense since this all occurs in one e2e test.

Putting cy.saveLocalStorage() when the info is saved and cy.restoreLocalStorage() when it should be displayed, does not help.

I have been Googling for hours.
Any ideas are welcome, thanks.

Comment: Do you have an access to the error backend log?

Comment: @Wandrille Yes, I do. Any suggestions as to what specifically should I be looking at or should share?

Comment: As it's an internal error, you should see in the logs of the backend the error. Could you add the log to your post ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick way forward might be to use an intercept and stub the response to POST appropriately.

```js
cy.intercept({
  method: 'POST',
  url: ...
},
{ 
  // stub response here, check devtools/Network for live response details
})
```

Comment: This answer lead to fixing the problem! Thank you so much!

I instead had to stub the Payload from devtools/Network, but close enough. 
Also, including an alias was better practice for intercepts like this, apparently.